Postman Xero API - AuthenticationUnsuccessful despite being standard collaborator of app
I'm not a software developer so I might be getting something basic wrong. I'm getting this error on postman.
{"Type":null,"Title":"Unauthorized","Status":401,"Detail":"AuthenticationUnsuccessful","Instance":"2fc25317-deed-44f0-86af-3a32b31110ff","Extensions":{}}
Essentially the company I work for has added me as a standard collaborator on the xero app.
see screenshot:

They are a lending company and have connected their customers xero accounts.
The devs have stored the 'tenantId', 'xerotoken', 'session_handle', and 'xerotoken_expiry' in a table.
I'm asking here because the Devs are in India and I can't really understand them and they do not provide me what I need.
I have followed the instructions here, https://developer.xero.com/documentation/sdks-and-tools/tools/postman/
And have placed clientID and clientSecret from the App I was  added to, and generated access token. See screenshot below.
I then have added the TenantID and access token from the table that was sent from the Devs in the highlights here. However, the access token is different from the one I generated in postman when pressing 'get new access token'.
I then get the error and am unable to pull anything.
Did I do a step incorrectly? Cheers


